# Is it possible to run GNOME 3 on Windows XP/Vista/7?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, gnome, gnome-shell

I want to install GNOME Shell and its core apps and features (including Natilus, Evolution, Empathy, Multiple workspace, and more) on a Windows 7 platform.

Is it possible to do that with or without Cygwin and Cygwin/X?

And if yes, can I remove Microsoft's own apps(Windows Explorer, IE, Windows Media Player, ...) and replace them with GNOME 3 Apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux software cannot run on Windows. Cygwin provides a way to compile software designed for Unix into something that may run on Windows. I've never used it so I can't say what the limitations are, but given the existence of CyGnome I would assume it's possible.

To avoid compiling yourself you could also check out CygWin Ports which says it has a Gnome 3 port, as well as Nautilus, and Empathy. ftp://sourceware.org/pub/cygwinports/portslist.txt . I've never used it so I don't know the specifics of getting it up and running.

Alteratively you might consider using CyGnome though it's Gnome 1, not Gnome 3.
http://cygnome.sourceforge.net/ They started a Gnome 2 port project, but it died. http://cygnome2.sourceforge.net/

Alternatively you might consider checking out GreenGnome instead. It's a port of Gnome 1 to Windows. The project is long since dead, and was from the XP era. http://translate.google.ca/translate?hl=en&sl=uk&u=http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greengnome&prev=/search%3Fq%3DGreenGnome%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DhgC%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26channel%3Dfflb . A long time ago I used this for a bit, and worked nicely.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016, the default Cygwin64 repositories contains Gnome 3 apps.

I installed these cygwin packages (and their dependencies) and I am now able to use Eye of GNOME 3.18 on Windows 7.

- eog
- xinit
- xorg

First, I open a cygwin bash terminal.  Then, I type `startxwin` and hit enter.  Two new tray icons appear.  One of them resembles the cygwin logo, but with a green X inside the black C.  I left click that tray icon and find Image Viewer on the Graphics menu.  When I click that, Eye of GNOME starts.  (And the 'auto refresh' feature works.)

Similar Gnome 3 apps probably work in the same way.

Comment: This old question is not about running GNOME 3 "Apps", but running "GNOME 3 Shell" on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

You can also run a full gnome-flashback (gnome 2 look on gnome 3) session now.

Just install gnome-flashback and xinit from the cygwin setup, GNOME Flashback shortcut will appear in your start menu in the Cygwin-X folder.

Comment: "just install gnome-flashback and xinit from the cygwin setup" - **How** does one do this?

Comment: download setup-x86_64.exe or setup-x86.exe from https://www.cygwin.com/ go through the wizzard and select xinit and gnome-flashback at the software selection.

Comment: Edit your answer.  I already know how, I raise question like that, when I see unclear answers in the review queue